# check if value exits in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmffL.png)

Here is a picture of my database. I want to check the type that is shown in the picture and if it has the value that I want, I will add a specific picture. If not, I will add another picture. I tried the code below, but it didn't work.

```
   let reference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


        reference.child("Quran/type").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChild("makya"){

                self.soraType.image = UIImage(named:"play")
            }else{
                self.soraType.image = UIImage(named:"pause") 
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referencing your node right, I think the line `if snapshot.hasChild("makya")` has to be "type", and not "makya".

Since "type" is the child of that snapshot, and "makya" is its value. Also, you can just get the value of the snapshot, and check if snapshot.value.type is "makya"

I'm not familiar with the exact iOS syntax, but basically that how it should be